# How to expand Woocommerce report

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I would Like to export a more complete report in WooCommerce in the report per category when I press Export CSV I only have the sold price per date

[image]

What I to have in the Export the VAT

I don't understand the [API](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/) and how it work

this is what I have when I do the export in csv

```
date       | category (selected) 

2015-5-11  | 65 (total for the day)
```

What I would like to have

```
date      | category  | w/Tax |   VAT  |  Buying Price w/TAX  |  VAT 

2015-5-11 | 65        | 54.17 | 10.83  |  20.83               | 4.17
```

I have the plugin WooCommerce and WooCommerce cost of goods

Comment: for this you need to make custom code.

Comment: Ok  but As I said I don't understand the API can you help me point me in the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

To add new row in csv file no need to check API that you shown. Plz check below files you get answer you need to add new row in “class-wc-report-sales-by-category.php” and add data from js file.

```
Here are two files:

1) /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-report-sales-by-category.php
2) /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/reports.min.js
```

Comment: I am on it all day. I am getting nower. Can you tell me the code plz

Comment: let me tell you one thing that category export use data of chart that we shown i try and get new rows in export file but it create problem in chart view. if you want to try then /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-report-sales-by-category.php line no 320. if you know coding then you make that but if you do't then it's hard to do that.